# What was Arya afraid of?

Tags: christopher-paolini, inheritance-cycle

In *Eldest*, when Eragon is traveling to the Du Weldenvarden, Eragon asks Arya what is wrong. Arya states, she is afraid. What was she afraid of?

For reference, this is found at the end of chapter Arya Svit-Kona, on page 164 in my copy of the book. It takes place immediately after Arya introduces Eragon in Elf customs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After reading further in the book, I discovered the answer.

> Arya was afraid to meet her mother, the Queen. The last time that she had seen her, there had been a fight, and she was afraid for what her mother might say or do. Still, she knew that it was required of her, so she did it.